# Resume Parsing to Profile2

Tags: 7, users

I'm looking for a module, integration or solution for parsing a resume on the profile fields.

Big companies like Monster.com and Indeed.com can provide you the ability to upload a resume and fill out all the fields of registration for you. One of my clients ask me for this feature on the website and I have no idea where to start.

Base of what I read online there are two module for parsing [Parsing Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/parsing_api) and [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) but they do not exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm using the Recruiter Distribution and Profile2.

My goal is to be able to upload a resume and that resume will complete their resume (Profile fields) for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have three options

a) either use third party resume services. I recommend best one [RChilli](http://www.rchilli.com) . We implemented them for various client.s

b) Or you can build your own algorithm for Resume Parsing.

c) 3rd one if you are getting fixed format of resumes then write own  using drupal parsing api.

Let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: Do you know if RChilli have a module for Drupal to integrate Drupal with their services?